# Why are the initial multiple selections of an Html.ListBox not visible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, listbox, multiple-select

I am testing a new plugin that converts a multiple-select ListBox to a set of multiple mutually-exclusive single-select drop-down lists. This should have been very straight-forward, as I just wanted to start with some items selected, but the answer eludes me so far.

I have reduced the problem to the following simple controller code (the plugin was turned off so is not a factor):

```
List<SelectListItem> selectList2 = db.LookupType.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Selected = x.LookupTypeId < 4, Value = x.LookupTypeId.ToString(), Text = x.Name }).ToList();
ViewBag.LookupTypeId2 = selectList2;
```

This will mark `Selected = true` on the first three items as the IDs start at 1 (confirmed in debugger that the first 3 items have `Selected = true`).

And the view looks like this:

```
@Html.ListBox("LookupTypeId2", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LookupTypeId2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

The resulting output however *has no selected items*:

```
<select name="LookupTypeId2" class="form-control" id="LookupTypeId2" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Degree</option>
    <option value="2">WorkdayLanguage</option>
    <option value="3">Language_Ability_Type_ID</option>
    <option value="4">National_ID</option>
    <option value="5">Phone_Device_Type_ID</option>
    <option value="6">Background_Check_Status_ID</option>
    <option value="7">Educational_Institution_Type_ID</option>
    <option value="8">Gender_Code</option>
    <option value="9">Military_Status_ID</option>
    <option value="10">Ethnicity_ID</option>
</select>
```

I have no problem selecting multiples with CTRL-Click etc, but the initial selections are not visible. What am I missing here?

**Update:** based on answer below I changed it to a ListBoxFor

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x=>x.LookupTypeId2, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LookupTypeId2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

have added the following value initialization:

```
List<SelectListItem> selectList2 = db.LookupType.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Selected = x.LookupTypeId < 4, Value = x.LookupTypeId.ToString(), Text = x.Name }).ToList();
lookup.LookupTypeId2 = new string[]{"1","2","3","4"};
ViewBag.LookupTypeId2 = selectList2;
```

Also tried with int array as suggested:

```
List<SelectListItem> selectList2 = db.LookupType.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Selected = x.LookupTypeId < 4, Value = x.LookupTypeId.ToString(), Text = x.Name }).ToList();
lookup.LookupTypeId2 = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
ViewBag.LookupTypeId2 = selectList2;
```

But still nothing is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need a property to bind to. A multiple select will only post back a collection of value types, but your trying to bind to `List<SelectListItem>`. Add a property (say) `public int[] SelectedItems { get; set; }` to your model and then use

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItems, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LookupTypeId2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Then if the values of `SelectedItems` matches any of the options, those options will be selected, for example if `model.SelectedItems = new int[] { 2, 10 };` then the 2nd and last options will be selected when you display the page. You do not (and should not) set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` when your binding to a property.

Comment: I do not wish to use ListBoxFor. Can you make this work with ListBox? (see update). I will try it with ListBox for now.

Comment: I did too, and it works fine so I can only assume you have something else interfering

Comment: Your edit still has identical property names for the property and the select list. They must be different.

Comment: Ah.. They must be the same for `ListBox`, but different for `ListBoxFor`. I will change the name and try again.

Comment: This works. I tried this and fixed the problem for me when I recreated @TrueBlueAussie's situation.

Comment: Okay. With `Html.ListBoxFor` the names cannot conflict *and that works*. for bonus points, how do you get the same result with `Html.Listbox` (where the property name must match the ViewBag list name)? :)

Comment: You could just write out the select tag the old fashioned way and foreach loop the options...

Comment: `@Html.ListBox("SelectedItems", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LookupTypeId2)` should also work  (different property names!)

Comment: Kaaaching!!! That is the opposite to what I have learned years ago, but you are correct. The list and property have to have unique names. Thank you for teaching an old dog :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you use `ListBox()` and not `ListBoxFor()`?

Comment: Now that you have pointed out the flaw in the naming, absolutely no reason. Q. What does the property have to look like to get the values posted back? I keep getting `null` for `LookupTypeId2`.

Comment: Do you mean when your return the view? Your only (and can only bind to value types, or arrays in the case of multiple select). Nothing relating to the `SelectList` properties (i.e. your `LookupTypeId2` ViewBag property) posts back when you submit a form, so if you return the view you need to repopulate the `SelectList`

Comment: This is all in an `Edit` action. `LookupTypeId2` is a model property. According to some posts it needs to be a single string value (which is wrong as that gives an error)

Comment: So I assume that meas you have changed the ViewBag property name. If your using `DropDownList` then the model property would need to be a value type (looks like it should be `int` based on your option values, but could be string). For `ListBox` it need to be `IEnumerable<int>` (or `IEnumerble<someOtherValueType>`). Are you saying that the selected values are not posting back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71159/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-stephen-muecke).